Does FreeBSD have copyfile()/fcopyfile()? If so, where can the documentation be found?
This StackOverflow answer How can I copy a file on Unix using C? claims that FreeBSD has copyfile()/fcopyfile() and has recieved 27 upvotes.
But FreeBSD Manual Pages found nothing for either copyfile() or fcopyfile(), and neither did BSD Man Pages.
OS X has has a man page for these functions here: fcopyfile(). Am I to supposed to use this documentation for FreeBSD as well?

Look at History section of OSX manpage

@kakkoko It says: "The copyfile() API was introduced in Mac OS X 10.5." I am aware of that. What did you mean to say?

@Harith so this function is introduced uniquely to OSX and is not found in FreeBSD.

@kakkoko I believe that is the case. My FreeBSD machine has no manual entry for copyfile() or fcopyfile(). A sample program that simply includes <copyfile.h> also fails to compile.

And grep -r fcopyfile /usr/include returns nothing...

@kakkoko Yes, it does not. I seem to have wasted my time. Thank you. :) Strange how that famous question has been viewed 163k times and there are no downvotes on the second top-voted answer.

@Downvoter/Closevoter I am not asking for any recommendations for software libraries or tutorials. You need not need open my questions if you see things that are not present. It is one StackOverflow's top-voted answer spreading misinformation, I do not see you there. And a hundred other questions asking about similar documentation have nearly all been upvoted.

FWIW, I found this in some software's release notes: "FreeBSD: Fix, fcopyfile is no longer available on newest OS version, and include files for sendfile have changed." As far as I can tell (from looking at github), that release was from 2022 or 2023.

The linked answer and its question are more than 10 years old. In CS things tend to change...

@thebusybee That's correct. But it is strange to see that a syscall just vanished and I find it difficult to trace its origins. :)

The answer (or any other claiming that FreeBSD has these functions) is either outdated or wrong . The fcopyfile()/copyfile() were introduced uniquely to OSX and are not found in FreeBSD.
FreeBSD has no manual entry for either copyfile() or fcopyfile(), and grep -r fcopyfile /usr/include and grep -r copyfile /usr/include return nothing. These functions have no equivalent in FreeBSD.
Though FreeBSD has copy_file_range() that one might be interested in.

In the comments above:

FWIW, I found this in some software's release notes: "FreeBSD: Fix,
fcopyfile is no longer available on newest OS version, and include
files for sendfile have changed." As far as I can tell (from looking
at github), that release was from 2022 or 2023. – Avi Berger

